# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, capistrano3

**Edit #1**

Here is the log

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [d8da8d91] Command: if test ! -d /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [d8da8d91] Finished in 0.495 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [64734ae3] Running $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec rake assets:precompile as poladmin@196.28.51.162

 DEBUG [64734ae3] Command: cd /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.1" RAILS_ENV="production" RAILS_GROUPS="" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec rake assets:precompile )

 DEBUG [64734ae3]       rake aborted!

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources

 DEBUG [64734ae3]       /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

 DEBUG [64734ae3]

Caused by:

 DEBUG [64734ae3]       LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

 DEBUG [64734ae3]       /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'

/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629192529/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

The `bundler` gem is installed on the server.

**Original Question**

So I'm trying to push my application to a server using capistrano, however, I'm getting a `LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup` error with the rake gem, however, locally rake is installed. Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rake', '~> 12.3', '>= 12.3.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'mongoid'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is `bundler` installed in your server? Could you `gem install bundler` before you run any rake task?

Comment: Please see edit 1 @LeoCorrea

Comment: Have you tried using Rails binstubs? (e.g running `bin/rake` instead of plain `rake`) this error normally happens when a path cannot be resolved to the gems. is `GEM_PATH` set in your server? I see you're using rbenv is it set correctly?

Comment: I am using rbenv yes I have also tried `bundle --binstubs`

Answer (score 0):

Try require false in gemfile.

```
    gem "capistrano", "~> 3.7",  require: false
    gem "capistrano-rails", "~> 1.2", require: false
```

Comment: Same error, still getting `Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `rbenv` or similar, your bundler and gems might be installed in a different env than your deploy login. You need to tell Cap that. I use this:

```
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'
set :rbenv_path, '/Users/stmpjmpr/.rbenv'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} /usr/local/bin/rbenv exec"
```

Comment: for the rbenv path and rbenv prefix am I using local paths or the server path?

Comment: They're from the context of the deploy user on the server, as though that user is SSHed in.

Comment: Ok here is the new log of what I'm getting now https://gist.github.com/benbagley/5dcd6b7d9476ba1aa2e77f0dd0375405 I have also added the Capfile there. The server is using Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: First: were you using `rbenv` to begin with? It looks like rbenv isn't installed in your user directory like it is on my server. Change the `set :rebenv_path` line to point where `rbenv` is on your system. You can determine this by SSHing in as your deploy user and using `which rbenv` and noting the directory it's in.

Comment: When I setup the server and my local development I always use rbenv, on the server when I do `which rbenv` I get `/home/poladmin/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`and locally on my desktop I get `/home/ben/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`

Comment: Now I'm getting https://gist.github.com/benbagley/5dcd6b7d9476ba1aa2e77f0dd0375405 still can't find the rake gem

Comment: Just ran gem list on the server and rake is installed see the gist

Comment: Log in as your deploy user and do a `which rake`; make sure that it's in your `PATH`.

Comment: It is, I mentioned this above and also updated the gist

Comment: It looks like your environment is still looking in the wrong place for its gems when running under Cap. I suggest making sure that Bundler is properly installed and configured. It needs to be installing gems where `rbenv` is going to use them. That may or may not be `$GEM_HOME`. There's got to be a disconnect in there, but it's too hard to troubleshoot in a comment.